# How to push onto Promise.all(Array)

Tags: javascript, promise

I don't think this is possible with the native promise implementation, but here's the basic idea of what I want:

```
const promises = [
    getSomething(),
    getSomethingElse(),
];

// combine promises
const alldone = Promise.all(promises);

// Add a promise after the previous ones have started
promises.push(getAThirdThing());

// everything, including `getAThirdThing` is done
await allDone;
```

In reality `Promise.all()` doesn't care that I pushed something onto the `promises` array.

Is there a similar pattern which accomplishes the same thing? Specifically, adding other promises to wait for, as they become known to a list of currently unresolved promises, arbitrarily, and without any requirement that any be added later.

I could do something like this instead:

```
const promises = [
    getSomething(),
    getSomethingElse(),
];
const alldone = Promise.all(promises);
await Promise.all([alldone, getAThirdThing()]);
```

But I want to call `.then()` on `allDone` prior to adding `getAThirdThing()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add promises to a set of promises and wait on a promise for them all to be fulfilled, with the ability to add additional promises to the set, there are at least two choices:

1. Create an onFulfilled handler, called by `then` that checks if more promises are waiting to be added, and if so returns a promise for them (all) to be settled chained to another promise using the same `then` handler. More or less akin to a recursive asynchronous method that adds promises if they are available. Keeping track of fulfilled results and matching them with promise operations, and avoiding uncaught rejection errors would still need attention.
2. Write a custom Promise static method or constructor that does what you want instead without using `Promise.all`.

As an example of 2., the `PromiseGroup` constructor below returns an object with

- a promise` property that is settled with an array of values in the order promises were added to the group, and
- an `add` method that adds promises to be settled in order of presentation.

```js
function PromiseGroup() {
    var resolve;
    var reject;
    this.promise = new Promise( (r, j) => { resolve = r, reject = j});
    this.settled = false;

    const group = this;
    var numAdded = 0;
    var numSettled = 0;
    const values = [];
    const quickReject = reason => reject(reason);
    const fulfill = ( i, value) => {
        values[i] =  value;
        if( ++numSettled === numAdded) {
            resolve( values);
            group.settled = true;
        }
    };
    this.add = function() {
        if( group.settled) {
            console.trace();
            throw new Error("Can't add promises to a settled group");
        }
        for( var j = 0; j < arguments.length; ++j) {
            let i = numAdded + j;
            Promise.resolve( arguments[j])
            .then( value => fulfill( i, value), quickReject);
        }
        numAdded += j;
    };
}

//********************************************     and test:

async function test() {
  var group = new PromiseGroup();
  group.add( new Promise(resolve=> setTimeout( resolve=>resolve(1), 500, resolve)),
             new Promise(resolve=> setTimeout( resolve=>resolve(2), 600, resolve)));
  setTimeout( test2, 100, group);
  var values = await group.promise;
  // some more code
  return values
}

function test2( group) { // add more after await
  group.add( new Promise(resolve=> setTimeout( resolve=>resolve(3), 700, resolve)),
             new Promise(resolve=> setTimeout( resolve=>resolve(4), 400, resolve)));
}

test().then( values=>console.log(JSON.stringify(values)));
```

The reasoning behind this answer is that `Promise.all`, and `Promise.race` are a minimal and low level set of promise aggregation methods and their presence need not preclude the development of new ones.

The wisdom of using `PromiseGroup` or similar is a separate consideration. Personally I would review overall asynchronous design of the application to see if optional promises could be combined with promise operations that determine their need, if possible, before ever reaching the `Promise.all` or group stage.

Comment: I used the first option and it worked very well and didn't add a lot of complexity. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

`Promise.all` returns a Promise itself, so you can call `Promise.all` consecutively:

```
let finished = Promise.all([...]);
finished = Promise.all([finished, someFunctionReturningAnotherPromise()]);
finished = Promise.all([finished, anotherFunctionReturningAPromise()]);
// etc...
// finally:
await finished;
```

However, what you *can't* do is add to the Promise chain *after* `await`ing the promise returned by `Promise.all`.

Also, things get a little tricky if in that scenario if you want to access the results of *all* the promises, as you'd end up with nested arrays of the results (which you could use something like [lodash.flattenDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/#flattenDeep) to normalize them).